# Problems with messageDelete in Discord js

Tags: javascript, node-modules, discord.js

I try to make my bot on Discord server. Want to make a function, which will copy all deleted message in text channel, but, `messageDelete` hear only deleted message which was writing after bot start. When I delete message which make earlier bot start, its not work.

```
{
client.on ("messageDelete", messageDelete =>{
    let channel = client.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'log-deleted-message')
    console.log(`Deleted :${messageDelete.content}`)
    channel.send(`${messageDelete.author.username} write : ${messageDelete.content}` 
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messageDelete` is an event that is called when a message is deleted while the bot is on. If a message is deleted before the bot is turned on there is no way to recover it, which is why it's known as deleted. The only way to accomplish the goal that you want is to leave the bot on permanently. Read more in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageDelete) if you want more information.

Comment: Nono, you are not understand me, sorry for my bad english. MessageDelete see only messages witch was send while bot work. If someone send message before bot start and then i start bot and try to delete it, messageDelete dont see this deleting message

Comment: @MikhailVeretelnikov is correct. Only cached messages which are deleted emit the event. There's really no way around this except to keep the bot online.

Comment: @slothiful The event will still be emitted for uncached messages which are deleted. However they will be a partial, so you need to enable partials. However, even with partials, if the bot was not online when the message was created and remained online up until the message was deleted, it will not be in the cache and the partial will only contain the message ID and not the contents. The contents will be unrecoverable.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is now outdated.
With Discord.js V12 you can now Cache messages on the messageDelete event, You would need to enable [Partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html). Once this is enabled, you can fetch the message beforehand like this:

```
if(message.partial){ 
let msg = await message.fetch()
console.log(msg.content)
}
```

That will then log the content of the previously uncached message.

Comment: Unfortunately, when a message is deleted you can no longer fetch it. So a delete on an uncached message will have only the id and nothing else.

Comment: When a message is deleted it is deleted, No argument there, What the OP is asking, is how to get messages that were sent when the bot was offline, to do this you need to enable partials, this will return the cache of messages that are in the channel. You are correct, In the fact that if messages were deleted, while the bot is offline, there would be nothing to grab from the cache, However if they were not deleted, then they would still be in the cache, and would be able to be logged and outputted when deleted to another channel, If the bot is online, which is what the user is asking.

Comment: I currently use exactly as you posted. If the bot was offline when the message was sent, it is uncached and fetching the partial will not recover it. Your answer will not recover the message. Additionally, even if the bot was online, if you have since taken it offline and brought it back online, that cache is lost and you cannot recover the deleted message.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, With my bot over here: https://github.com/Tricky-Ricky/Discmod - I am able to log prior messages if my bot has gone offline, and then bought back online, by using partials. The code above is not the whole story, merely a snippet showing how to do it that relies on other factors as linked in the partials documentation. Again, If this message has been edited/deleted while the bot is offline then it is not possible to retrieve. The bot is also not what does the caching, so before you continue this, I would highly recommend you go look at their api more.

Comment: That seems highly unlikely since you skip partials in your `messageDelete` code: https://github.com/Tricky-Ricky/Discmod/blob/master/Events/messageDelete.js#L5-L7

Comment: Their API guide also explicitly supports what I said, "You can not fetch data from the API that's already deleted. For message deletions messageDelete will only emit with the ID, which you can not use to fetch the complete message containing content, author or other information for, as it is already inaccessible by the time you receive the event." https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#handling-partial-data So I would highly recommend you go look at their API more.

Comment: You are seriously mis-interpreting what the question is...
He wants to know how to log WHEN they are deleting it, WHILE his bot is on. If his bot is not on, then no he cannot recover or log deleted messages, IF his bot is on, then yes, on the messageDelete event, you can grab the content of the message and output it into another channel as a log, but only IF his bot is online - I am saying in the context of this question, this is how you do it, if his bot is not on, then he has no way of doing it, You really should look at the context of the question and what you are trying to argue.

Comment: You are being seriously argumentative on this forum, both on mine, and others answers, who have answered correctly what the OP has asked, and are trying to argue something outside of the scope of his question, Which was already answered in the above answer, I merely adapted my answer to that of his, with the updated version - Which as the answer states NEEDS his bot to be on, although you are correct that messages cannot be recovered if his bot is offline, All answers have already explicitly stated that, and you are being argumentative, so please stop.

Comment: By caching the message through partials, the older messages that haven't been deleted, but get deleted while the bot is online, can be logged. If you don't get the cache, then any previous messages sent when the bot is offline, which when deleted  if the bot is online, are unable to be logged due to not getting the cached data.

Comment: I'm not arguing pointlessly. The original question included the concern that they were unable to recover the contents of the message for messages which had been created prior to the bot starting. Please actually read the full original question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920870/problems-with-messagedelete-in-discord-js/64232779?noredirect=1#comment98504301_55923441

Comment: "although you are correct that messages cannot be recovered if his bot is offline, All answers have already explicitly stated that, and you are being argumentative, so please stop"

Comment: Your answer does not explicitly say that Partials do not work with the `messageDelete` event. With that event, they will only ever emit the id, not any conent. It is misleading until it is updated to say as such. This is explicitly stated in the docs. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#handling-partial-data Please update your answer.

Comment: No, what you have linked there states that partials are only ever guaranteed to have the content ID, meaning they may or may not have the content aswell. It depends on a factor of things.

I would recommend that instead of attacking me and my answer, that you create your own answer - with your own thoughts, as of Disccord.js v12 my answer is correct in the context it is written.